# Use values from another function python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have this code, but i dont know how to use the "age" from the user in the other function any clue what i have wrong?

```
def accounts():
    yourCode = input("Please enter your user code. \nIf you already have an account, type your account user code. \nOtherwise, enter a new one to create an account: ")

   
    with open("users.txt", "r") as rf:
        users = rf.readlines() 
        for each_user in [user.split(",") for user in users]: 
            if each_user[0] == yourCode: 
                print(f"Welcome {each_user[1]}") 
                age = each_user[2]
                xxApp() 
                return None 
    with open("users.txt", "a") as af:
        name = input("Please enter your name: ")
        age = input("Enter your age: ")
        af.write(f"{yourCode},{name},{age}\n") 
        print(f"Thank you {name}, your information has been added.")
        xxApp()


def xxApp():
    age = each_user[2]
    print(age)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a parameter

```
def accounts():
    yourCode = input("Please enter your user code. \nIf you already have an account, type your account user code. \nOtherwise, enter a new one to create an account: ")

   
    with open("users.txt", "r") as rf:
        users = rf.readlines() 
        for each_user in [user.split(",") for user in users]: 
            if each_user[0] == yourCode: 
                print(f"Welcome {each_user[1]}") 
                xxApp(each_user) 
                return None 
    ...


def xxApp(user):
    age = user[2]
    print(age)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're defining `age = each_user[2]`, but the `each_user` variable is only available in the scope of `accounts()`.

[You can read about python scopes here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp)

I would modify the `xxApp()` function to take in a variable as a parameter like this

```py
def xxApp(each_user):
    age = each_user[2]
    print(age)
```

then you call `xxApp()` with the `each_user` passed as a parameter, so it is available inside the scope of `xxApp()`, like this `xxApp(each_user)`